# Alterar a versão do PHP do composer

Tags: php, composer

O composer no meu servidor está reconhecendo o PHP 5.6, mas estou usando o PHP 7.1 em outro diretório. Como eu faço para alterar a versão do PHP do composer?

Comment: você utiliza o apache ? da um phpinfo() e vê qual versão o servidor está usando

Comment: Sim, utilizo apache.

Sobre o phpinfo(), se eu der esse comando na raiz, a versão que me aparece é a 5.6.33.

Porém, se eu der esse comando em public_html, a versão que me aparece é a 7.0.27

Comment: ta usando Windows ?

Comment: Não, estou usando um servidor linux, ainda não sei se é ubuntu ou qual distribuição.

Comment: Utilize `screenfetch`, `lsb_release -a` ou `uname -a` para descobrir a distro do seu Linux. Se você utiliza duas ou mais versões do PHP no Linux, utilize o [PHPBrew](http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/) para gerenciar.